# Get First Single matched element or First if there's no match?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, dapper

Is that possible in **LINQ** to write a nice one-liner to get a **first matched element or if there's no match than get first element** in the collection?

E.g. you have a collection of parrots and you want yellow parrot but if there's no yellow parrots - then any will do, something like this:

```
Parrots.MatchedOrFirst(x => x.Yellow == true)
```

I'm trying to avoid double-go to SQL Server and the ORM we use in this particular case is [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for pointing out to the conversation about tags in questions and editing the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: It was a linq to SQL solution

First building a handy extension

```
public static T MatchedOrFirstOrDefault<T>(this IQueryable<T> collection, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)
{
  return (from item in collection.Where(predicate) select item)
                    .Concat((from item in collection select item).Take(1))
                    .ToList() // Convert to query result
                    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Using the code

```
var matchedOrFirst = Parrots.MatchedOrFirstOrDefault(x => x.Yellow);
```

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
var matchedOrFirst = Parrots.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Yellow == true) 
    ?? Parrots.FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit**

For structs, this should work:

```
var matchedOrFirst = Parrots.Any(x => x.Yellow == true) 
    ? Parrots.First(x => x.Yellow == true)
    : Parrots.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Should just be `?? Parrots.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, my current implementation is `Parrots.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Yellow == true) ?? Parrots.First()` but (I guess I should have mentioned that) I wanted to avoid multiple round-trips to SQL Server.

Comment: @user1249170 If you need this to be a SQL Server LINQ thing, you should tag the question with which ORM you are using, LINQ-to-SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc. because the answer would vary from one to the next.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a 2nd SQL call and since requires branching logic, its unlikely that Dapper will know how to convert a LINQ query you come up with into appropriate SQL IIF, CASE, or whatever other SQL-specific functions you end up using.

I recommend you write a simple stored procedure to do that and call it from Dapper.

Depending on its usage though, if this page only has one or two queries on it already, and is located reasonably close (latency wise) to the server, a 2nd simple SELECT won't hurt the overall application that much. Unless it is in a loop or something, or your example is trivial compared to the actual query regarding the cost of the first SELECT.